# Split a string, loop through it character by character, and replace specific ones?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on an assignment and have gotten stuck on a particular task. I need to write two functions that do similar things. The first needs to correct capitalization at the beginning of a sentence, and count when this is done. I've tried the below code:

```
def fix_capitalization(usrStr):
count = 0
fixStr = usrStr.split('.')
for sentence in fixStr:
    if sentence[0].islower():
        sentence[0].upper()
        count += 1
print('Number of letters capitalized: %d' % count)
print('Edited text: %s' % fixStr)
```

Bu receive an out of range error. I'm getting an "Index out of range error" and am not sure why. Should't `sentence[0]` simply reference the first character in that particular string in the list?

I also need to replace certain characters with others, as shown below:

```
def  replace_punctuation(usrStr):
    s = list(usrStr)
    exclamationCount = 0
    semicolonCount = 0
    for sentence in s:
        for i in sentence:
            if i == '!':
                sentence[i] = '.'
                exclamationCount += 1
            if i == ';':
                sentence[i] = ','
                semicolonCount += 1
    newStr = ''.join(s)
    print(newStr)
    print(semicolonCount)
    print(exclamationCount)
```

But I'm struggling to figure out how to actually do the replacing once the character is found. Where am I going wrong here?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you allowed to use the built-in function string.replace()?

Comment: @KuboMD I am and have tried that but have the same issue in referencing the particular character. Any idea how that could be done?

Comment: By the way - sentence[0].upper() doesn't do anything. You need to make a second string to add the letters back into. .upper() needs to be assigned to a variable; and you can't assign it to itself due to the nature of a string being immutable.

Comment: `'5.'.split('.') ` results in `['5', '']` can you see the issue in trying to access 0 index without an empty-string check?

Comment: As long as you're working from the left, you can limit the # of replacements so it only replaces the one character that you want to delete. `string.replace("old char", "new char", 1)`

Comment: @ParitoshSingh I'm not sure what you're getting at. In all test cases the original string is a few sentences long.

Comment: do any* original strings end with a period? @CameronMcMains

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Yes they do. All of them except for the very last one does

Comment: @KuboMD I tried doing `newStr[sentence] = sentence.replace(sentence[0], sentence[0].upper(), 1)` but it throws the error "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str." So I'm back to square one :(

Comment: @CameronMcMains you cant do `newStr[sentence] = sentence.replace(sentence[0], sentence[0].upper(), 1)` because you are trying to use an string as an index in another string, it expects an integer!!

Comment: @Cameron if you use the second string, no need for replace. `newStr[i] = sentence[i].upper()` ; of course in a `for i in sentence` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `str.capitalize` over `str.upper` on one character.  It also works correctly on empty strings.  The other major improvement would be to use `enumerate` to also track the index as you iterate over the list:

```
def fix_capitalization(s):
    sentences = [sentence.strip() for sentence in s.split('.')]
    count = 0
    for index, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
        capitalized = sentence.capitalize()
        if capitalized != sentence:
            count += 1
            sentences[index] = capitalized
    result = '. '.join(sentences)
    return result, count
```

You can take a similar approach to replacing punctuation:

```
replacements = {'!': '.', ';': ','}

def replace_punctuation(s):
    l = list(s)
    counts = dict.fromkeys(replacements, 0)
    for index, item in enumerate(l):
        if item in replacements:
            l[index] = replacements[item]
            counts[item] += 1
    print("Replacement counts:")
    for k, v in counts.items():
        print("{} {:>5}".format(k, v))
    return ''.join(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to do these things but I'll try to change your code minimally so you will learn something.
The first function's issue is that when you split the sentence like "Hello." there will be two sentences in your fixStr list that the last one is an empty string; so the first index of an empty string is out of range. fix it by doing this.

```
def fix_capitalization(usrStr):
    count = 0
    fixStr = usrStr.split('.')
    for sentence in fixStr:
        # changed line
        if sentence != "":
            sentence[0].upper()
            count += 1
    print('Number of letters capitalized: %d' % count)
    print('Edited text: %s' % fixStr)
```

In second snippet you are trying to write, when you pass a string to list() you get a list of characters of that string. So all you need to do is to iterate over the elements of the list and replace them and after that get string from the list.

```
def  replace_punctuation(usrStr):
    newStr = ""
    s = list(usrStr)
    exclamationCount = 0
    semicolonCount = 0
    for c in s:
        if c == '!':
            c = '.'
            exclamationCount += 1
        if c == ';':
            c = ','
            semicolonCount += 1
        newStr = newStr + c
    print(newStr)
    print(semicolonCount)
    print(exclamationCount)
```

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

Python has a nice build in function for this

```
for str in list:
    new_str = str.replace('!', '.').replace(';', ',')
```

You can write a oneliner to get a new list

```
new_list = [str.replace('!', '.').replace(';', ',') for str in list]
```

You also could go for the split/join method

```
new_str = '.'.join(str.split('!'))
new_str = ','.join(str.split(';'))
```

To count capitalized letters you could do

```
result = len([cap for cap in str if str(cap).isupper()])
```

And to capitalize them words just use the

```
str.capitalize()
```

Hope this works out for you